# Integrating GIT with Jenkins

Tags: linux, git, github, jenkins

I am trying to add git repo-url to jenkins so that jenkins can build my code and run some tests. But the repo I am using is private and that's where I am running into issues. Here is the error that I get when I add the GIT repo url in Jenkins under Source COde Management-

```
  Failed to connect to repository : Command "/usr/local/bin/git ls-remote -h 
    git@github.com:xxxx/xxx.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
    stdout:
    stderr: ERROR: Repository not found.
    fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I am aware that one cause for this would be as the repo is private it would require a username and password to authenticate. Any ideas on how to make this as passwordless authentication?

Comment: Do you use gitolite as git keeper?

Comment: Can you connect over ssh? With your user?

Comment: I cannot. I have also added the SSH key in GitHub

Comment: Usually you have a dedicated user under which you run jenkins. Configure it to access your git repository ()with netrc or ssh key) and check that you can run git ls-remote. This should solve your problem.

Comment: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Plugin

Perhaps you can use the github plugin

Comment: tigran - I am using a dedicated jenkins user and when i run git ls-remote it gives me a authentication error. My guess here is it needs a username and password as its a private repo so the I want to make it passwordless.

Comment: stony- I am using the plugin

Answer (score 0):

the below links might be helpful to you -

> https://github.com/Tozkoparan/Deneme/wiki/Setup-Jenkins-for-working-with-a-private-Github-repository
>
> http://fourkitchens.com/blog/2011/09/20/trigger-jenkins-builds-pushing-github

Comment: first link gives a 404 